# Android Studio и gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Плавно перехожу с Eclipse.
А можно как-то сделать, чтобы для всех новых проектов использовалась моя папка с gradle соответствующей версии?

А то сейчас получается она создаёт с 2.8, берёт этот gradle из подпапки android studio. И только после создания проекта, я могу зайти в настройки и указать версию и локальную папку с gradle.

А мне по большому счёта и папка gradle в android studio не надо. Потому что у меня разные версии gradle в совсем другом месте лежат.

Answer (score 1):

`ctrl`+`shift`+`A`
*Global gradle settings*
*Use local gradle distribution*
и указать путь к локальному градлу
должно помочь